# Send Information From A Webpage To Another

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know this is almost duplicated, a lot of people asked that and a lot answered them by `PHP Form` but I really didn't find anything for my problem.
I have a page called `platforms.php` and this page has a group of image-links which are: `Windows`,`Mac`, `Android` and `iOS`.
So what I want is when somebody clicks the `Windows` link (as an example) they go to a page called `download.php` and the page should say `You are using Windows!`.
Please not that I  don't want to create a page for every link, I want it to be one page only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use condition for each case on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send an  extra parameter in your url and then in the same single page use the condition like:
let the parameter name be `'pagetype'`.

download.php

```
if ($_REQUEST['pagetype'] == 'windows')
{
//your output for windows
}
else if ($_REQUEST['pagetype'] == 'mac')
{
   //your output for mac
}
else if(..)
{
.
.
.
```

**Note:**
You can replace `$_REQUEST`, with `$_GET` or `$_POST`, depending on method you use to post data to this page

Comment: Chosen as best answer for the note.

Answer (score 2):

Make URL like that

```
<a href = "http://example.com/download.php?device=window" >Window</a>
<a href = "http://example.com//download.php?device=mac" >Mac</a>
```

On your page download.php

```
if(isset($_GET['device'])) {
    $device = $_GET['device'];
}

if ($device == 'window' ) {
        // window message here
} elseif ($device == 'mac' ) {
    // mac message here
}
```

Comment: very simple solution!!Great!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have an HTML link and send the data through GET parameters. Something like (in `platforms.php`):

```
<a href="download.php?os=Windows >Windows</a>

<a href="download.php?os=Mac >Mac</a>

<a href="download.php?os=Android >Android</a>

<a href="download.php?os=iOs >iOs</a>
```

And then in `downloads.php`, getting the variable `"os"` and do whatever you want with it:

```
if ( isset($_GET['os'] ) ) {
     echo "You are using " . $_GET['os'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add image like

```
<a href="download.php?key=window"><img src="window.jpg"/></a>
<a href="download.php?key=ios"><img src="ios.jpg"/></a>
```

and on **download.php** page you can check

```
$value = $_GET['key'];
if(value== 'window')
if(value== 'ios')

etc
```

hope this is what you want.